# Modify module namespace before load

Tags: python, import, module

I'm creating a plugin system which works by loading a Python module during runtime.

For each plugin, there is an associated toolbar button in the GUI.  When the plugin module defines a specific function (e.g. `run_plugin()`), a toolbar action is created which executes the function when clicked.  Some plugins require access to this button, for instance, to control whether the button is enabled, disabled, checked, unchecked, etc.

The way I currently handle this is to either store the GUI element in a dict which is then accessed from the plugin module (via `from __main__ import main_window`) or by updating the module's `__dict__` directly after load.

These solutions work fine when the GUI element is accessed through the run function.  However, such elements are not accessible at the file module level.  It would be nice to have access there.

Can I create and modify a module's namespace before the associated file is executed?  If I try to modify the module or spec prior to `spec.loader.exec_module()`, I get errors:

```
pdb> spec['banana'] = 'green banana'
*** TypeError: 'ModuleSpec' object does not support item assignment

pdb> plugin_module['banana'] = 'a banana'
*** TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment
```

Basically, when I import a plugin module, I would like for certain variables to be defined, just as with `__name__`, `__dict__`, etc.

---

Here's a minimal sample of the plugin system/application:

**Application with plugin system**

```py
# application.py
import os
import sys

import importlib
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

MY_PLUGIN = "c:/projects/my_plugin.py"


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.plugins = {}

        self.plugin_toolbar = self.addToolBar('Plugin Toolbar')

        # Menu
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.plugin_load_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Load plugin...', self)
        self.plugin_load_action.triggered.connect(self.on_plugin_load)

        self.file_menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu('&File')
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.plugin_load_action)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # Central widget
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def on_plugin_load(self):

        # Emulate file dialog
        path = MY_PLUGIN

        plugin_dir, plugin_file = os.path.split(path)
        plugin_name = os.path.splitext(plugin_file)[0]

        loader = SourceFileLoader(plugin_name, path)
        spec = spec_from_loader(plugin_name, loader)
        plugin_module = module_from_spec(spec)

        if plugin_module:
            if plugin_name not in self.plugins:
                try:
                    print(f"Loading '{plugin_name}'...", flush=True)
                    spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module)
                    sys.modules[plugin_name] = plugin_module
                    self.plugins[plugin_name] = {'module': plugin_module}
                except Exception as err:
                    print(f'{err}', flush=True)
            else:
                print('Reloading...', flush=True)
                try:
                    plugin_module = self.plugins[plugin_name]['module']
                    importlib.reload(plugin_module)
                except ImportError as err:
                    print(f'Import error: {err}', flush=True)

        # Get the plugin run function
        plugin_run_func = plugin_module.__dict__.get('run_plugin')

        # Attach run function to toolbar action
        plugin_icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_TitleBarMenuButton)
        plugin_toolbar_action = QtWidgets.QAction(plugin_icon, plugin_name, self)
        plugin_toolbar_action.triggered.connect(plugin_run_func)
        self.plugin_toolbar.addAction(plugin_toolbar_action)

        # Give plugin module access to the toolbar action
        plugin_module.__dict__['TOOLBAR_ACTION'] = plugin_toolbar_action

        print(f'Plugin loaded', flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Sample plugin**

```py
# c:/project/my_plugin.py

TOOLBAR_ACTION = None

def run_plugin():
    print(f'Running plugin...', flush=True)
    print(f'The toolbar action is: {TOOLBAR_ACTION}', flush=True)

print(f'The toolbar action is: {TOOLBAR_ACTION}', flush=True)
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to call like `plugin_module.init_plugin(plugin_toolbar_action)`? That way, all of your initialization code can run whenever you want it to, with whatever globals & arguments you want it to.

Comment: I'm certainly open to the idea.  I'm not sure I follow you, however.  The `plugin_module` is the module object returned by `importlib.util.module_from_spec`.  AFAICT, I can't modify attributes of it.  I'm not sure what you mean by `plugin_module.init_plugin`.